# firebase database streaming with python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, streaming

it shows     my_stream = db.child("users").stream(stream_handler)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import pyrebase
from configruation import config
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db =firebase.database()


def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"]) # put
    print(message["Name"]) # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["Email"]


my_stream = db.child("users").stream(stream_handler)
```

Comment: There’s no closing parentheses after the last print

Comment: thanks for help i ave not reviwed my code.